# TSQL CTE error ''Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part"

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Would someone help me understand the details of the error below..? This is for SQL Server 2008.

I did fix it myself, and found many search hits which show the same fix, but none explain WHY this happens in a CTE.

> Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "txt" of recursive query "CTE".

Here is an example where I resolved the issue with CAST, but why does it work?

```
WITH CTE(n, txt) AS
(
    --SELECT      1, '1'                          --This does not work.
    --SELECT      1, CAST('1' AS varchar)         --This does not work.
    --SELECT      1, CAST('1' AS varchar(1000))   --This does not work.
    SELECT      
        1, 
        CAST('1' AS varchar(max))                 --This works. Why?
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      
        n+1, 
        txt + ', ' + CAST(n+1 AS varchar)         --Why is (max) NOT needed?
    FROM        
        CTE
    WHERE       
        n < 10
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

I assume there are default variable types at play which I do not understand, such as:

- what is the type for something like `SELECT 'Hello world!` ?
- what is the type for the string concatenation operator `SELECT 'A' + 'B'` ?
- what is the type for math such as `SELECT n+1` ?

Comment: You really should upgrade from 2008 to a supported version, it's been EOL for a while already

Comment: `varchar` without a length defaults to `varchar(30)` in a cast, and `varchar(1)` everywhere else. The answers to your last 3 questions are all in the docs: `varchar(12)` `varchar(2)` and `int` respectively, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @ Charlieface yes, I'm aware of the EOL issue. Not an option, as it's not my box. Also, the question and it's reason still apply, regardless of the version. And yes, if it was 2012+ I might be able to figure it out with @kendle's answer below, but not necessarily. There are still type issues at play which I may not be aware of.

Comment: @ Charlieface and thank you for the 2nd comment. That helps with my understanding. I would not have been able to determine the information you provided out of the lined document. I'll read it again and maybe it'll sink in, but that's a little bit...dense for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info you want is [all in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> When concatenating two char, varchar, binary, or varbinary expressions, the length of the resulting expression is the sum of the lengths of the two source expressions, up to 8,000 bytes.
>
> *snip* ...
>
> When comparing two expressions of the same data type but different lengths by using `UNION`, `EXCEPT`, or `INTERSECT`, the resulting length is the longer of the two expressions.
>
> The precision and scale of the numeric data types besides `decimal` are fixed. When an arithmetic operator has two expressions of the same type, the result has the same data type with the precision and scale defined for that type.

However, a recursive CTE [is not the same](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions) as a normal `UNION ALL`:

> The data type of a column in the recursive member **must be the same** as the data type of the corresponding column in the anchor member.

So in answer to your questions:

- `'Hello world!'` has the data type `varchar(12)` by default.
- `'A' + 'B'` has the data type `varchar(2)` because that is the sum length of the two data types being summed (the actual value is not relevant).
- `n+1` is still an `int`
- In a recursive CTE, the data type must match *exactly*, so `'1'` is a `varchar(1)`. If you specify `varchar` without a length in a `CAST` then you get `varchar(30)`, so `txt + ', ' + CAST(n+1 AS varchar)` is `varchar(33)`.

When you cast the anchor part to `varchar(max)`, that automatically means the recursive part will be `varchar(max)` also. You don't need to cast to `max`, you could also cast the recursive part directly to `varchar(30)` for example:

```
WITH CTE(n, txt) AS
(
    --SELECT      1, '1'                          --This does not work.
    SELECT      1, CAST('1' AS varchar(30))         --This does work.
    --SELECT      1, CAST('1' AS varchar(1000))   --This does not work.
    UNION ALL
    SELECT      
        n+1, 
        CAST(CONCAT(txt, ', ', n+1) AS varchar(30))
    FROM        
        CTE
    WHERE       
        n < 10
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7a0c75871003315bb28060d499a4651a)

Comment: Thank you for all of that. I <did> try to check the documentation, but didn't come close to finding answers. And admittedly....had I found my way to that page for Precision, Scale, and Length, I would not have recognized it as what I sought. It's a bit deep for my current level of understanding, but not so much after reading it now. Thank you. <thumbsup>

Answer (score 0):

If you place the query into a string then you can get the result set data types like with the query :

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';

EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set @query, NULL, 0;
```

Comment: Alternatively, `SELECT system_type_name FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'SELECT ''Hello world!''',NULL,0)`, which eliminates the noise.

Comment: sp_describe_first_result_set isn't available on SQL 2008.

Comment: Testing an individual expression for type and length can often be done with [`SQL_Variant_Property`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): `select SQL_Variant_Property( C, 'BaseType' ) as BaseType, SQL_Variant_Property( C, 'MaxLength' ) as MaxLengthInBytes, SQL_Variant_Property( C, 'TotalBytes' ) as TotalBytes from ( values ( 'A' + 'B' ) ) as T(C);`. Try changing `'A' + 'B'` to `'A' + N'B'` or some other expression of interest to see the results. Note that it can also return `Precision` and `Scale` for numeric values.